# can't commit js, css, jpg files into subversion repository svn: E175002: PROPFIND 405 Not Allowed

Tags: svn, http-status-code-405

When I commit js, css or jpg file via http into subversion repository, I get the error.

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/testproj/trunk/123.css': 405 Not Allowed (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)
```

But commiting php/html/tpl has no problem. How to prevent this error?

my svn config (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf)

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/data/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  #<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  #</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

My svn version is 1.6.17
My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: Your `DocumentRoot` in Apache is ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a web server to communicate with your repositories. Having these error (Method not allowed) seems to be a problem of the web server to access the files.

If your repository is not in the standard document root of the webserver you need to tell the server that users are allowed to access those directories.

As for the apache webserver a simple

```
<directory Path/to/your/repositories>
  Allow from all
</directory>
```

in the apache config should do the job.

Comment: if this doesn't work, checkout this [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/11996/subversion-error-405-method-not-allowed-in-response-to-mkcol/133880#133880)

Comment: I added it to the end of my svn config (dav_svn.conf)
<directory /var/www/fastwax/data/svn/ >
 Allow from all
</directory>
I restarted apache, but the error is still there.